# How to configure bashrc to go to previous session working directory

Tags: linux, bash

While logging in to linux system using ssh, by default it goes to user working directory. e.g. /root for root user.
I want to configure my bashrc so that if I log in next time it takes me to previous working directory of root user.

Comment: Your question is based on the assumption that a user is always logged into exactly one or zero sessions at the same time, but this is a patently false assumption. How do you decide which of possibly dozens of recent sessions to recreate? Is the answer the same if you log in twice in rapid succession?

Comment: @tripleee I would assume this to work the same way as the (broken) Bash history configuration of most distributions: The value which survives is the one from the last closed shell.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you work with a single user, you can add something like this.

1. Create a `.bash_logout` file and save your current directory to a known file:

   ```
   pwd >"$HOME/.last_directory"
   ```
2. Then, in `.bashrc` file read that file and `cd` into the directory.

   ```
   dir="$(<"$HOME/.last_directory")"
   [ -d "$dir" ] && cd "$dir"
   ```

Things to be aware of:

1. This solution *should* work for spaces, but might need additional tweaking.
2. This will work for one user only - that is, the `.bashrc` and `.bash_logout` "owner". If you intend this to work for multiple users (e.g. yourself and `root`), one solution is to create similar instructions in each user's `.bashrc` and `.bash_logout`, but make them use common `.last_directory` file independent from current `$HOME`. The other option is to use system wide `/etc/bash.bash_logout` and `/etc/bas.bashrc` (as suggested by [l0b0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96588/l0b0)).
3. Abruptly closing your session using signals (= closing the terminal instead of typing `exit`, `logout` or hitting `^D`), or network disconnections in case of SSH, will result in `.bash_logout` **not** firing, which won't save your directory.

Comment: You should be able to configure this system wide by using `/etc/bash.bash_logout` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`.